# Making a button reverse to the original condition

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the theme of the ViewController with a button. I want to interchangeably change betweeen a black and a white background. So if I tap the button, the theme should turn white. If I tap again, the theme should become black again..and so on.
 I currently have this:

```
@IBAction func themeBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        var doubleTap = false
        if (doubleTap) {
            //Second Tap
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            doubleTap = false
        } else {
            //First Tap
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            doubleTap = true
        }
    }
```

Xcode tells me that these lines will never be executed :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
doubleTap = false
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `var doubleTap = false` Declare this var outside the func

Comment: `@IBAction func themeBtn(_ sender: Any) {
       self.view.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor == UIColor.black ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
    }`  Just use this.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `doubleTap` variable outside your function.

Also, your code can be much cleaner by using **ternary operators**.

```
var doubleTap = false

@IBAction func themeBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    doubleTap = !doubleTap
    view.backgroundColor = doubleTap ? .white : .black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your doubleTap var is always false.

You must init the doubleTap var outside the function (e.g. in the viewDidLoad).